# Is a Google Maps API request to AuthenticationService a billing event?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We have customer (Google Enterprise license) who asked us to implement a google-maps-api button on the front page of the site but that does not display any map-tile (to avoid being billed for people who do not view the map). The DIV that contains the map is rendered by AngularJS ng-if (will be inserted into the DOM when the user requests the map). The only outgoing request when displaying the page (after loading the API itself with https_//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?client=gme-xxx&v=3), is a request to the URL
https_//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate

From my understanding this should not be a billable map-view, according to this FAQ: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload

Is this correct?

However the user complains about exceeding the quota, and claims that the call to this URL is using up quota: https_//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?client=gme-xxx&v=3&key=xxx

After the map is opened by pressing the button the web-page sends https_//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/QuotaService.RecordEvent
This should then be the billable "map-view" event?

[Note: Sorry, that I have asked this question here, but this is the official community-support by google-maps-api.]

Comment: I believe loading the API constitutes a "map load", whether or not it is used to actually display a map.

Comment: This would be bad as it contradicts to Google's FAQ that I mentioned above and will slow down loading. Probably I should post a bug to the issue tracker?

Comment: UPDATE: I have confirmed this works as documented for the __free quota__ API-key. But our customer complains this is different for the enterprise key.

Answer (score 0):

Great! Quotas are calculated differently for Enterprise License customers and free API. Here the answer from Google Support:

I have taken a look at your issue, and see that you are referring to the free API documentations. For the free API it is true that the quota is only consumed when you display a map. However, the quota limits are different for Maps for Work customer: according to the FAQ here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#pageview, the quota is consumed when a page view is made. A page view is a load of the Google Maps JavaScript API into a page, regardless of whether you display a map or not.